# Decrypting in pgpy fails with "ValueError: Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data"

Tags: python, encryption, gpgpu, pgp, openpgp

I have an OpenPGP encrypted file and its private key in a text file and know its passphrase.

I tried this below code:

```
import pgpy

emsg = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file('PGPEcrypted.txt')
key,_  = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file('PrivateKey.txt')
with key.unlock('passcode!'):
    print (key.decrypt(emsg).message)
```

But while trying to execute I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project\PGP\pgp_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    key,_  = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file('SyngentaPrivateKey.txt')
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pgpy\types.py", line 191, in from_file
    po = obj.parse(data)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pgpy\pgp.py", line 2252, in parse
    unarmored = self.ascii_unarmor(data)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pgpy\types.py", line 131, in ascii_unarmor
    raise ValueError("Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data")
ValueError: Expected: ASCII-armored PGP data
```

How can I decrypt the file in python?

Comment: Did you use the -a flag when you exported the private key?

Answer (score 0):

OpenPGP knows two message formats: the binary encoding (more space-efficient) and the base64-like ASCII-armoring (better compatibility especially with old internet protocols). `pgpy.from_file` only loads ASCII armored messages. If you've messages in the binary format, use `pgpy.from_blob` instead. From the [`pgpy` documentation](https://pgpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#loading-existing-messages):

> #### Loading Existing Messages
>
> Existing messages can also be loaded very simply. This is nearly
>   identical to loading keys, except that it only returns the new message
>   object, instead of a tuple:
>
> ```
> # PGPMessage will automatically determine if this is a cleartext message or not
> message_from_file = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_file("path/to/a/message")
> message_from_blob = pgpy.PGPMessage.from_blob(msg_blob)
> ```